# Change the datasource of widget in a Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a wordpress theme and i want to change the data that is displayed on a widget.

My theme is [Bloom](http://themeforest.net/item/bloom-sleek-new-magazine-theme/8677950) and the widget is this

[image: widget]

I need to diplay in the tabs a rss feed for which one. What do i have to change? Can i do it on the administration panel?

Comment: I think you better ask at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks!